# Angular 4 | Transitions don't work with conditional css classes

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I've been searching stackoverflow for a while now and I don't think this has been answered yet. I Have a conditional class on a div that gets added to the div when a boolean variable is set to true. Following code:

```
<div [class.modalwindow-show]="modalState" class="modals">

    [...]

</div>
```

When the user clicks a button the variable is set to true and the class modalwindow-show gets added to the div. My problem is that out of some reason the css transition is not working, the background just changes without a transition. I have these two classes:

```
.modals{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all .30s ease-in-out;
}

.modalwindow-show{
    background: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
    display: block;
}
```

Does anyone know why the transition is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I entirely removed display: none and display: block and am now using visibility: hidden and visibility: visible. display was overriding the transition.

```
.modals{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all .30s ease-in-out;
}

.modalwindow-show{
    visibility: visible;
    background: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
}
```

Comment: I was just going to post the same. yes, the transition doesn't go with display: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uazrlb?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Post it as an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thank you! But you already answered and will be able to mark as answer in a few hours :)